# How to fix position of div tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am creating an interactive Periodic Table for my Project.[image]

This looks well and good, but as soon as I change the resolution, the right side elements scatter all over the page and it all becomes a mess.
[image]

**Here is the snippet:-**

```js
function Lanthanoids() {
  var elements1 = document.getElementsByClassName('lanthanoids');
  var i, marginLeft = -70;

  for (i = 0; i < elements1.length; i++) {
    marginLeft += parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(elements1[i]).marginLeft, 10) + 70;
    elements1[i].style.marginLeft = marginLeft + 'px';
  }
}

function Actinoids() {
  var elements2 = document.getElementsByClassName('actinoids');
  var i, marginLeft = -70;

  for (i = 0; i < elements2.length; i++) {
    marginLeft += parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(elements2[i]).marginLeft, 10) + 70;
    elements2[i].style.marginLeft = marginLeft + 'px';
  }
}

function TypesHover() {
  $('.info').hover(
    function() {
      getId = this.id;
      originalColor = document.getElementById(getId).style.backgroundColor;
      originalAll = document.querySelector('div').style.backgroundColor;
      switch (getId) {
        case "alkali_metals":
          $(".info:not(#lithium, #sodium, #potassium, #rubidium, #cesium, #francium, .types, .typesCont)").css("background-color", "D3D3D3");
          break;

        case "alkaline_earth_metals":
          $(".info:not(#beryllium, #magnesium, #calcium, #strontium, #barium, #radium, .types, .typesCont)").css("background-color", "D3D3D3");
          break;

        case "transition_metals":
          $(".info:not(#scandium, #titanium, #vanadium, #chromium, #manganese, #iron, #cobalt, #nickel, #copper, #zinc, #yttrium, #zirconium, \
                #niobium, #molybdenum, #technitium, #ruthenium, #rhodium, #palladium, #silver, #cadmium, #hafnium, #tantalum, #tungsten, \
                #rhenium, #osmium, #iridium, #platinum, #gold, #mercury, #rutherfordium, #dubnium, #seaborgium, #bohrium, #hassium, #meitnerium, \
                #darmstadtium, #roentgenium, #copernicium, .types, .typesCont)").css("background-color", "D3D3D3");
          break;

        case "post_transition_metals":
          $(".info:not(#aluminium, #gallium, #indium, #tin, #thalium, #lead, #bismuth, #ununtrium, #flerovium, \
                #ununpentium, #livemorium, .types, .typesCont)").css("background-color", "D3D3D3");
          break;

        case "lanths":
          $(".info:not(#lanthanum, #cerium, #praseodymium, #neodymium, #promethium, #samarium, #europium, #gadolinium, #terbium, #dysprosium, \
                #holmium, #erbium, #thulium, #ytterbium, #lutetium, #lanths_space, .types, .typesCont)").css("background-color", "D3D3D3");
          break;

        case "acts":
          $(".info:not(#actinium, #thorium, #protactinium, #uranium, #neptunium, #plutonium, #americium, #curium, #berkilium, #californium, \
                #einsteinium, #fermium, #mendelivium, #nobelium, #lawrencium, #acts_space, .types, .typesCont)").css("background-color", "D3D3D3");
          break;

        case "other_non_metals":
          $(".info:not(#hydrogen, #carbon, #nitrogen, #oxygen, #phosphorus, #sulphur, #selenium, .types, .typesCont)").css("background-color", "D3D3D3");
          break;

        case "halogens":
          $(".info:not(#flourine, #chlorine, #bromine, #iodine, #astatine, #ununseptium, .types, .typesCont)").css("background-color", "D3D3D3");
          break;

        case "noble_gases":
          $(".info:not(#helium, #neon, #argon, #krypton, #xenon, #radon, #ununoctium, .types, .typesCont)").css("background-color", "D3D3D3");
          break;

        case "metalloids":
          $(".info:not(#boron, #silicon, #germanium, #arsenic, #antimony, #tellurium, #polonium, .types, .typesCont)").css("background-color", "D3D3D3");
          break;

        default:
          $(".info").css("background-color", originalAll);
      }
    },
    function() {
      document.getElementById(getId).style.backgroundColor = originalColor;
      // document.querySelector('div').style.backgroundColor = originalAll;
      $(".info").css("background-color", originalAll);
    });
}

function Slider(val) {
  var slider = document.getElementById("temperature");
  var val = slider.value;
  originalAll = document.querySelector('div').style.backgroundColor;
  document.getElementById('amount').innerHTML = val + "K";

  // switch(val)
  // {
  //     case "28":
  //     $('#hydrogen, #helium, #neon').css("background-color", "red");
  //     break;

  //     case "56":
  //     $('#oxygen, #flourine').css("background-color", "blue");
  //     break;

  //     case "84":
  //     $('#nitrogen').css("background-color", "red");
  //     $('#argon').css("background-color", "blue");
  //     break;
  // }
  if (val >= 28) {
    $('#hydrogen, #helium, #neon').css("background-color", "red");
  }
  if (val >= 56) {
    $('#oxygen, #flourine').css("background-color", "blue");
  }
  if (val >= 84) {
    $('#nitrogen').css("background-color", "red");
    $('#argon').css("background-color", "blue");
  }
  if (val >= 112) {
    $('#hydrogen, #helium, #neon, #oxygen, #flourine, #nitrogen, #argon').css("background-color", "red");
  }
  if (val >= 140) {
    $('#krypton').css("background-color", "red");
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', Lanthanoids, false);
window.addEventListener('load', Actinoids, false);
window.addEventListener('load', TypesHover, false);
window.addEventListener('load', Slider, false);
```

```css
* {
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

img {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 70px auto;
  margin-right: 70px auto;
}


body {
 background-color: #eafeef;
}

p {
  font-size: 5px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

h2 {
  line-height: 60px;
}

.para {
  font-size: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

em {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 7px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

div {
  display: inline;
  box-shadow: none;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
}

div:hover div:not(.typesCont):hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px #000000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px #000000;
}

.types {
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
  height: 35px;
  width: 80px;
  line-height: 15px;
  left: 260px;
  top: 50px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

#metals,
#non_metals,
#metalloids {
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
}

#metals {
  width: 325px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 235px;
  background-color: #9faeb8;
}

#non_metals {
  width: 170px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: -110px;
  margin-left: 600px;
  background-color: #9faeb8;
}

#metalloids {
  height: 30px;
  width: 109px;
  line-height: 30px;
  top: 23px;
  left: 847px;
  background-color: #8ee39c;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: left top 0;
}

#alkali_metals {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #ffcc33;
}

#alkaline_earth_metals {
  left: 340px;
  background-color: #ffff64;
}

#transition_metals {
  left: 420px;
  background-color: #ddbbbb;
}

#post_transition_metals {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  left: 500px;
  background-color: #abe3d5;
}

#other_non_metals {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  left: 627px;
  background-color: #4dff4d;
}

#halogens {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 30px;
  left: 707px;
  background-color: #4bf1d5;
}

#noble_gases {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  top: 85px;
  left: 665px;
  background-color: #89d3ff;
}

#lanths {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 25px;
  top: 85px;
  left: 340px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #ffc3a6;
}

#lanths_space {
  margin-left: 210px;
  margin-top: 247px;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: 800px;
  background-color: #ffc3a6;
}

#acts {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 25px;
  top: 85px;
  left: 420px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #f0c6e2;
}

#acts_space {
  margin-left: 210px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #f0c6e2;
}

.row4,
.row5,
.row6,
.row7,
.row8,
.row9,
.row10,
.row11,
.row12 > div:nth-child(1),
.row3 > div:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top: 232px;
}

.row3 > div,
.row4 > div,
.row5 > div,
.row6 > div,
.row7 > div,
.row8 > div,
.row9 > div,
.row10 > div,
.row11 > div,
.row12 > div,
.row13 > div,
.row14 > div,
.row15 > div,
.row16 > div {
  background-color: #ddbbbb;
}

.row1 > div {
  background-color: #ffcc33;
}

.row1 > #lithium,
.row2 > div:nth-child(1),
.row13 > div:nth-child(1),
.row18 > div:nth-child(2),
.row14,
.row15,
.row16,
.row17 {
  margin-top: 92px;
}

.row2 > div {
  background-color: #ffff64;
}

.row17 > div {
  background-color: #49f1d5;
}

.row18 > div {
  background-color: #8Bd3ff;
}

#hydrogen {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #42ff42;
  left: 78px;
  top: 30px;
}

#helium {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #8Bd3ff;
  top: 30px;
  right: 11px;
  /*right: 28px;*/
}

#carbon,
#nitrogen,
#oxygen,
#phosphorus,
#sulphur,
#selenium {
  background-color: #4fff4f;
}

#boron,
#silicon,
#germanium,
#arsenic,
#antimony,
#tellurium,
#polonium {
  background-color: #8ee39c;
}

#aluminium,
#gallium,
#indium,
#tin,
#thalium,
#lead,
#bismuth,
#ununtrium,
#flerovium,
#ununpentium,
#livemorium {
  background-color: #abe3d5;
}

.lanthanoids,
.actinoids {
  position: absolute;
}

.lanthanoids {
  background-color: #ffc3a6;
  top: 530px;
  left: 220px;
}

.actinoids {
  background-color: #f0c6e2;
  top: 600px;
  left: 220px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div class="typesCont">
    <div class="types info" id="alkali_metals"><a href="#openModal">Alkali Metals</a></div>
    <div class="types info" id="alkaline_earth_metals"><a href="#openModal">Alkaline Earth Metals</a></div>
    <div class="types info" id="transition_metals"><a href="#openModal">Transition Metals</a></div>
    <div class="types info" id="post_transition_metals"><a href="#openModal">Post Transition Metals</a></div>
    <div class="types info" id="metalloids"><a href="#openModal">Metalloids</a></div>
    <div class="types info" id="other_non_metals"><a href="#openModal">Other Non-Metals</a></div>
    <div class="types info" id="halogens"><a href="#openModal">Halogens</a></div>
    <div class="types info" id="noble_gases"><a href="#openModal">Noble Gases</a></div>
    <div class="types info" id="lanths"><a href="#openModal">Lanthanoids</a></div>
    <div class="types info" id="acts"><a href="#openModal">Actinoids</a></div>
    <div class="info" id="metals"><a href="#openModal">Metals</a></div>
    <div class="info" id="non_metals"><a href="#openModal">Non-Metals</a></div>
    <div class="info" id="lanths_space"><a href="#openModal">57-71</a></div>
    <div class="info" id="acts_space"><a href="#openModal">89-103</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row1">
    <div class="info" id="hydrogen"><a href="#openModal"><em>1</em>H<p>Hydrogen</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="lithium"><a href="#openModal"><em>3</em>Li<p>Lithium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="sodium"><a href="#openModal"><em>11</em>Na<p>Sodium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="potassium"><a href="#openModal"><em>19</em>K<p>Potassium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="rubidium"><a href="#openModal"><em>37</em>Rb<p>Rubidium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="cesium"><a href="#openModal"><em>55</em>Cs<p>Cesium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="francium"><a href="#openModal"><em>87</em>Fr<p>Francium</p></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
    <div class="info" id="beryllium"><a href="#openModal"><em>4</em>Be<p>Beryllium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="magnesium"><a href="#openModal"><em>12</em>Mg<p>Magnesium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="calcium"><a href="#openModal"><em>20</em>Ca<p>Calcium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="strontium"><a href="#openModal"><em>38</em>Sr<p>Strontium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="barium"><a href="#openModal"><em>56</em>Ba<p>Barium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="radium"><a href="#openModal"><em>88</em>Ra<p>Radium</p></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row3">
    <div class="info" id="scandium"><a href="#openModal"><em>21</em>Sc<p>Scandium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="yttrium"><a href="#openModal"><em>39</em>Y<p>Yttrium</p></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row4">
    <div class="info" id="titanium"><a href="#openModal"><em>22</em>Ti<p>Titanium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="zirconium"><a href="#openModal"><em>40</em>Zr<p>Zirconium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="hafnium"><a href="#openModal"><em>72</em>Hf<p>Hafnium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="rutherfordium"><a href="#openModal"><em>104</em>Rf<p>Rutherfordium</p></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row5">
    <div class="info" id="vanadium"><a href="#openModal"><em>23</em>V<p>Vanadium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="niobium"><a href="#openModal"><em>41</em>Nb<p>Niobium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="tantalum"><a href="#openModal"><em>73</em>Ta<p>Tantalum</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="dubnium"><a href="#openModal"><em>105</em>Db<p>Dubnium</p></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row6">
    <div class="info" id="chromium"><a href="#openModal"><em>24</em>Cr<p>Chromium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="molybdenum"><a href="#openModal"><em>42</em>Mo<p>Molybdenum</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="tungsten"><a href="#openModal"><em>74</em>W<p>Tungsten</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="seaborgium"><a href="#openModal"><em>106</em>Sg<p>Seaborgium</p></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row7">
    <div class="info" id="manganese"><a href="#openModal"><em>25</em>Mn<p>Manganese</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="technitium"><a href="#openModal"><em>43</em>Tc<p>Technitium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="rhenium"><a href="#openModal"><em>75</em>Re<p>Rhenium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="bohrium"><a href="#openModal"><em>107</em>Bh<p>Bohrium</p></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row8">
    <div class="info" id="iron"><a href="#openModal"><em>26</em>Fe<p>Iron</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="ruthenium"><a href="#openModal"><em>44</em>R<p>Ruthenium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="osmium"><a href="#openModal"><em>76</em>Os<p>Osmium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="hassium"><a href="#openModal"><em>108</em>Hs<p>Hassium</p></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row9">
    <div class="info" id="cobalt"><a href="#openModal"><em>27</em>Co<p>Cobalt</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="rhodium"><a href="#openModal"><em>45</em>Rh<p>Rhodium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="iridium"><a href="#openModal"><em>77</em>Ir<p>Iridium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="meitnerium"><a href="#openModal"><em>109</em>Mt<p>Meitnerium</p></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row10">
    <div class="info" id="nickel"><a href="#openModal"><em>28</em>Ni<p>Nickel</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="palladium"><a href="#openModal"><em>46</em>Pd<p>Palladium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="platinum"><a href="#openModal"><em>78</em>Pt<p>Platinum</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="darmstadtium"><a href="#openModal"><em>110</em>Ds<p>Darmstadtium</p></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row11">
    <div class="info" id="copper"><a href="#openModal"><em>29</em>Cu<p>Copper</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="silver"><a href="#openModal"><em>47</em>Ag<p>Silver</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="gold"><a href="#openModal"><em>79</em>Au<p>Gold</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="roentgenium"><a href="#openModal"><em>111</em>Rg<p>Roentgenium</p></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row12">
    <div class="info" id="zinc"><a href="#openModal"><em>30</em>Zn<p>Zinc</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="cadmium"><a href="#openModal"><em>48</em>Cd<p>Cadmium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="mercury"><a href="#openModal"><em>80</em>Hg<p>Mercury</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="copernicium"><a href="#openModal"><em>112</em>Cn<p>Copernicium</p></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row13">
    <div class="info" id="boron"><a href="#openModal"><em>5</em>B<p>Boron</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="aluminium"><a href="#openModal"><em>13</em>Al<p>Aluminium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="gallium"><a href="#openModal"><em>31</em>Ga<p>Gallium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="indium"><a href="#openModal"><em>49</em>In<p>Indium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="thalium"><a href="#openModal"><em>81</em>Ti<p>Thalium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="ununtrium"><a href="#openModal"><em>113</em>Uut<p>Ununtrium</p></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row14">
    <div class="info" id="carbon"><a href="#openModal"><em>6</em>C<p>Carbon</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="silicon"><a href="#openModal"><em>14</em>Si<p>Silicon</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="germanium"><a href="#openModal"><em>32</em>Ge<p>Germanium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="tin"><a href="#openModal"><em>50</em>Sn<p>Tin</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="lead"><a href="#openModal"><em>82</em>Pb<p>Lead</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="flerovium"><a href="#openModal"><em>114</em>Fl<p>Flerovium</p></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row15">
    <div class="info" id="nitrogen"><a href="#openModal"><em>7</em>N<p>Nitrogen</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="phosphorus"><a href="#openModal"><em>15</em>P<p>Phosphorus</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="arsenic"><a href="#openModal"><em>33</em>As<p>Arsenic</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="antimony"><a href="#openModal"><em>51</em>Sb<p>Antimony</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="bismuth"><a href="#openModal"><em>83</em>Bi<p>Bismuth</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="ununpentium"><a href="#openModal"><em>115</em>Uup<p>Ununpentium</p></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row16">
    <div class="info" id="oxygen"><a href="#openModal"><em>8</em>O<p>Oxygen</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="sulphur"><a href="#openModal"><em>16</em>S<p>Sulphur</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="selenium"><a href="#openModal"><em>34</em>Se<p>Selenium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="tellurium"><a href="#openModal"><em>52</em>Te<p>Tellurium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="polonium"><a href="#openModal"><em>84</em>Po<p>Polonium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="livemorium"><a href="#openModal"><em>116</em>Lv<p>Livemorium</p></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row17">
    <div class="info" id="flourine"><a href="#openModal"><em>9</em>F<p>Flourine</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="chlorine"><a href="#openModal"><em>17</em>Cl<p>Chlorine</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="bromine"><a href="#openModal"><em>35</em>Br<p>Bromine</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="iodine"><a href="#openModal"><em>53</em>I<p>Iodine</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="astatine"><a href="#openModal"><em>85</em>At<p>Astantine</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="ununseptium"><a href="#openModal"><em>117</em>Uux<p>Ununseptium</p></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row18">
    <div class="info" id="helium"><a href="#openModal"><em>2</em>He<p>Helium</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="neon"><a href="#openModal"><em>10</em>Ne<p>Neon</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="argon"><a href="#openModal"><em>18</em>Ar<p>Argon</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="krypton"><a href="#openModal"><em>36</em>Kr<p>Krypton</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="xenon"><a href="#openModal"><em>54</em>Xe<p>Xenon</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="radon"><a href="#openModal"><em>86</em>Rn<p>Radon</p></a></div>
    <div class="info" id="ununoctium"><a href="#openModal"><em>118</em>Uuo<p>Ununoctium</p></a></div>
  </div>
  <div id="lanths" style="height: 0px">
    <div class="lanthanoids info" id="lanthanum"><a href="#openModal"><em>57</em>La<p>Lanthanum</p></a></div>
    <div class="lanthanoids info" id="cerium"><a href="#openModal"><em>58</em>Ce<p>Cerium</p></a></div>
    <div class="lanthanoids info" id="praseodymium"><a href="#openModal"><em>59</em>Pr<p>Praseodymium</p></a></div>
    <div class="lanthanoids info" id="neodymium"><a href="#openModal"><em>60</em>Nd<p>Neodymium</p></a></div>
    <div class="lanthanoids info" id="promethium"><a href="#openModal"><em>61</em>Pm<p>Promethium</p></a></div>
    <div class="lanthanoids info" id="samarium"><a href="#openModal"><em>62</em>Sm<p>Samarium</p></a></div>
    <div class="lanthanoids info" id="europium"><a href="#openModal"><em>63</em>Eu<p>Europium</p></a></div>
    <div class="lanthanoids info" id="gadolinium"><a href="#openModal"><em>64</em>Gd<p>Gadolinium</p></a></div>
    <div class="lanthanoids info" id="terbium"><a href="#openModal"><em>65</em>Tb<p>Terbium</p></a></div>
    <div class="lanthanoids info" id="dysprosium"><a href="#openModal"><em>66</em>Dy<p>Dysprosium</p></a></div>
    <div class="lanthanoids info" id="holmium"><a href="#openModal"><em>67</em>Ho<p>Holmium</p></a></div>
    <div class="lanthanoids info" id="erbium"><a href="#openModal"><em>68</em>Er<p>Erbium</p></a></div>
    <div class="lanthanoids info" id="thulium"><a href="#openModal"><em>69</em>Tm<p>Thulium</p></a></div>
    <div class="lanthanoids info" id="ytterbium"><a href="#openModal"><em>70</em>Yb<p>Ytterbium</p></a></div>
    <div class="lanthanoids info" id="lutetium"><a href="#openModal"><em>71</em>Lu<p>Lutetium</p></a></div>
  </div>
  <div id="acts" style="height:0px">
    <div class="actinoids info" id="actinium"><a href="#openModal"><em>89</em>Ac<p>Actinium</p></a></div>
    <div class="actinoids info" id="thorium"><a href="#openModal"><em>90</em>Th<p>Thorium</p></a></div>
    <div class="actinoids info" id="protactinium"><a href="#openModal"><em>91</em>Pa<p>Protactinium</p></a></div>
    <div class="actinoids info" id="uranium"><a href="#openModal"><em>92</em>U<p>Uranium</p></a></div>
    <div class="actinoids info" id="neptunium"><a href="#openModal"><em>93</em>Np<p>Neptunium</p></a></div>
    <div class="actinoids info" id="plutonium"><a href="#openModal"><em>94</em>Pu<p>Plutonium</p></a></div>
    <div class="actinoids info" id="americium"><a href="#openModal"><em>95</em>Am<p>Americium</p></a></div>
    <div class="actinoids info" id="curium"><a href="#openModal"><em>96</em>Cm<p>Curium</p></a></div>
    <div class="actinoids info" id="berkilium"><a href="#openModal"><em>97</em>Bk<p>Berkilium</p></a></div>
    <div class="actinoids info" id="californium"><a href="#openModal"><em>98</em>Cf<p>Californium</p></a></div>
    <div class="actinoids info" id="einsteinium"><a href="#openModal"><em>99</em>Es<p>Einsteinium</p></a></div>
    <div class="actinoids info" id="fermium"><a href="#openModal"><em>100</em>Fm<p>Fernium</p></a></div>
    <div class="actinoids info" id="mendelivium"><a href="#openModal"><em>101</em>Md<p>Mendlivium</p></a></div>
    <div class="actinoids info" id="nobelium"><a href="#openModal"><em>102</em>No<p>Nobelium</p></a></div>
    <div class="actinoids info" id="lawrencium"><a href="#openModal"><em>103</em>Lr<p>Lawrencium</p></a></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried resetting values, fiddled with positioning of elements but for some reason it doesn't work. I am unable to find that reason as of now? How can I make any changes so that divs are fixed at their positions. Any tip or help is appreciated.

Comment: Before give a proper answer, you have to tell how you want the layout to look like when what's there now will not fit. Should all go smaller, should it jump into new lines, and if so, how and in which order, ....

Comment: I want these elements to be fixed at their positions, no jumping around.

Comment: Then you should close this question, ask a new one, targeting the real issue, as what you just wrote has nothing to do with responsive layout, it is about persist a layout that breaks when viewport gets smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give a % width to the div and its elements or you can try to do it using bootstrap columns, it's a good way to make a responsive design!

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Answer (score -1):

You could try using media queries in the CSS to re-size the element boxes to fit on smaller screens. You will need to consider a different layout for mobile as you won't get that layout to work on a 320px wide screen unless you start hiding content, like he full name and number part.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

    #metalloids {
        height: 15px;
        width: 66px;
    }

}

@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

    #metalloids {
        height: 30px;
        width: 109px;
    }

}
```